# How do iphone apps update their SQLite data from the internet?

Tags: iphone, xml, sqlite

I think iphone apps have a database somewhere, and when a user updates data in application it contacts the server and gets an xml from the database and parses it? Am i right? I want to be able to create apps that tranfer data through the internet but i dont know how. Is xml the correct way to do it? If yes, then how can i convert a SQLite saved to my PC into a xml file and send it to iphone?

Answer (score 0):

XML is often used for transferring data, and many iOS-based apps do use SQLite for data storage. That said, there's not a single "correct" format for transferring or storing data -- do what works best for your situation.